# object references an unsaved transient instance when mapping is @ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two tables and objects : StudentsInGroup and GroupRegistration.

```
class StudentInGroup {
@Id
@Column (name = "ID")
private Integer id;

// other fields

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = GroupRegistration.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_CODE")
private GroupRegistration groups;

// other methods
}


class GroupRegistration {
@Id
@Column (name = "ID")
private Integer Id;

// other fields

@Column(name = "GROUP_CODE")
private Integer groupCode;  // this is not primary key

// other methods
}
```

I have form and method insertStudentInGroup(StudentInGroup student); but when I invoke this method I got exception  : object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: StudentInGroup.groups -> GroupRegistration

I saw that people had this kind of problem but they used cascades , I don't need cascades. Can anybody help me.

Comment: Your naming is extremely confusing: why name the field `groups` since it contains only one group registration? It should be named `group` or `groupRegistration`. Why name the column GROUP_CODE in StudentInGroup since it doesn't reference the GROUP_CODE column of GroupRegistration, but the ID column? It sould be named GROUP_ID.

Comment: @JBnizet column name GROUP_CODE is true because it references GROUP_CODE column of GroupRegistration, it is not ID, it is group code

Comment: No, it doesn't reference GROUP_CODE. It would only if you added `referencedColumnName="GROUP_CODE"` to the JoinColumn annotation. Otherwise, it references the ID of the target entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use cascade, then you need to save **GroupRegistration** (non-owning side) first before you save **StudentInGroup** (owning side), otherwise it will not be able to know how to do the mapping for you, therefore show the TransientObjectException. Hope it would help you.

Comment: GroupRegistration is already saved. I have saved GroupRegistrations and now I want to register students in registered Groups (GroupRegistration)

Comment: I solved this problem :) I was helped by my co-worker

Comment: here i face the same problem. Can you explain it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may save your time:

If **GroupRegistration** is already existing, While saving **StudentInGroup** you need to ensure that **GroupRegistration** property is properly set to null or need to check if it's holding proper ID(primary key) value.

```
Employee emp = new Employee();//or from UI modal.
emp.setDept((emp.getDept().getDeptId != null) ? new Dept(emp.getDept().getDeptId) : null); 
//When getting from UI, we need to explicitly set the property to null to make hibernate happy.:-)
em.persist(emp);
```